# Smallest compiler ever

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, turing-complete, brainfuck

Yesterday, I stuck in the internet with this article about programming language called `BrainFuck`.
http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/

So what is wonder me is this

```
  Brainfuck is the ungodly creation of Urban Müller, whose goal was apparently 
to create a Turing-complete language for which he could write the smallest
compiler ever, for the Amiga OS 2.0.  His compiler was 240 bytes in size. 
(Though he improved upon this later -- he informed me at one point that
he had managed to bring it under 200 bytes.)
```

So, is it smallest compiler of Turing-complete programming languages really today?
And is it proven that smaller compiler doesn't exist anyway?

Is there any results in this area. It's really interested me, is there any smallest value of size of Turing-complete programming language's compiller and what is that value?

Comment: This is not the right forum for this question.

Comment: I guess if tags are supported, question must be supported too.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, @mesiesta. But this question is really not about programming. It's more about history and world-records and such. This forum is for programmers to discuss programming problems with code samples.

Comment: I think, it's more interesting to dig into questions like this...
Tuning-completement is very-very interesting. I suggest you to check about it.

Comment: The problem is more complex than what you'd normally find at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, but they'd probably answer the OP's question with another world's record.

Comment: @mesiesta, yes, it is *very* interesting. But we have another forum to discuss such things. This is not that forum.

Answer (score 11):

The size of the smallest possible BrainFuck compiler is totaly machine dependant. Therefore, if you speak about a certain value you must always consider the architecture it is running on.

## The smallest possible BrainFuck compiler is 0bytes

The architecture this compiler is running on, has the neat property of beeing able to interpret Brainfuck Sourcecode natively. It has the even neater property, that a programs output resides at the same memory locations as its input does.

The byte code of the smallest posssible BrainFuck Compiler is then: "". Since this program terminates immediately, it does not apply any modifications to the input. Therefore the output of a run from this program always equals the input from this run. Since the architecure can execute BrainFuck natively, this program turns BrainFuck Sourcecode into binary code for this architecture. The program is therefore a BrainFuck compiler for this architecture.

## Real Word Architectures

Unfortunetly the architecture described above is not applicable to real world applications, but neither is BraickFuck.

Comment: +1 for a real smart down vote without actually down voting.